# Why Java type inference doesn't work for return value with parameterized type?

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic type that implements a generic interface. Java compiler correctly infers the constraint in the type parameter of the type in all cases but fails to do so in one.

See `getValue()` method implementation in Generic class below:

```
package test.gen.company;

public class GenericProblem {
    Generic<ISpecific> gen = new Generic<>();
    //compiler has no problems here
    ISpecific val = gen.getValue();

    Generic<IMoreSpecific> gen2 = new Generic<>();
    //both of these are OK
    ISpecific val1 = gen2.getValue();
    IMoreSpecific val2 = gen2.getValue();

    //compiler won't allow this,
    //correctly complains irrelevant is not within bounds
    //Generic<Irrelevant> gen;
}

interface IGeneric<T>{
    T getValue();
    void setValue(T in);
}
interface ISpecific {}
interface IMoreSpecific extends ISpecific {}
interface Irrelevant{}
class ISpecificImplementer implements ISpecific {}

class Generic<T extends ISpecific> implements IGeneric<T> {

    @Override
    public T getValue() {
        //error: required T, found ISpecificImplementer
        return new ISpecificImplementer();

        //Unchecked cast
        //return (T) new ISpecificImplementer();
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(T in) {
        //no complaints here, compiler knows T is ISpecific
        wantSomeB(in);
    }

    private void wantSomeB(ISpecific in){
        if (in == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("I'm completely meaningless");
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler sets the type of parameter in `setValue(T in)` to `T extends ISpecific` based on the type parameter of `Generic` but it cannot set the type of `T` in `T getValue()`

When I use a cast to `T` in `getValue()` it then complains about an unchecked cast.

Why is type inference working for the setter but not for the getter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`T` in `Generic<T extends ISpecific>` is allowed to be *any type extending `ISpecific`*.

That means it *could* be `ISpecificImplementer`, or it *could* be some other matching type. The choice of `T` isn't up to the method to decide; it's up to whatever creates the `Generic<T>` instance.

Inside `getValue()`, you're trying to return an `ISpecificImplementer`. Now `T` *might* be `ISpecificImplementer`, or it might be some other type that is not compatible. So it requires a cast. And casting to a generic type generates a warning, because it is bypassing the type-safety that generics are intended to provide.

Suppose that `SomeOtherType` is another class implementing `ISpecific`.
If you instantiate a `Generic<SomeOtherType>` and call `getValue()`, you'll end up with a casting exception, because `getValue()` *should* return a `SomeOtherType`, but it will *actually* try and return a `ISpecificImplementer`. That's why there's a compile warning.

Comment: You're right, the really helpful bit in your answer is 'the choice of T isn't...' I'd kindly like to point out that you cannot instantiate `Generic<SomeOtherType>` though, as included in the code in my question. `getValue()` returning a less specialised type then what is expected by the creator of `Generic<T>` is the potential problem the compiler is protecting use from. Just in case you want your helpful answer to be 100% correct :)

Comment: @GrumpyRodriguez I'm not sure what you mean "you cannot instantiate `Generic<SomeOtherType>`" — if `SomeOtherType` implements `ISpecific` then you can, can't you? Is that what wasn't clear in my answer?

Comment: apologies yes, it is in your answer, but I somehow missed it. my bad.

Comment: @GrumpyRodriguez No problem: I added it into my answer to make it clear.